# Roundtrip legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, legend-properties

Here's a little code snippet:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.errorbar([1, 2, 3], [1, 1, 1], yerr=[.1, .1, .1], c='orange', label='orange')
ax.legend()
ax.plot([1, 2, 3], [2, 2, 2], c='blue', label='blue')
leg = ax.get_legend()
```

It looks like this:

[image]

Now, if I was given `leg`, how could I recreate the legend?

I have tried

```py
ax.legend(leg.legendHandles, [i.get_text() for i in leg.get_texts()])
```

However, this doesn't preserve the maker info (notice how now the line in the legend is just a straight line, rather than a line with an error bar through it)

[image]

I have also tried

```py
ax.legend(*ax.get_legend_handles_labels());
```

however this adds a new line which wasn't visible in the original legend.

[image]

---

### EDIT

If the original plot was

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.errorbar([1, 2, 3], [1, 1, 1], yerr=[.1, .1, .1], c='orange', label='orange')
ax.plot([1, 2, 3], [3, 3, 3], c='green', label='green')
ax.legend()
ax.plot([1, 2, 3], [2, 2, 2], c='blue', label='blue')
leg = ax.get_legend()
```

, which looks like this:
[image]

then I would want to keep both the orange and the green lines. Basically, I want to keep only what's already visible in the legend, while `ax.get_legend_handles_labels` gives me everything back.

### EDIT2

A 1-1 mapping between `leg.legendHandles` and `ax.get_legend_handles_labels()` would allow for this to be accomplished, can that be done?

Comment: @DavidG that works in this specific instance, but isn't at all generic, so I can't use it

Comment: Is the generic question, how to include only lines plotted using `errorbar` in the legend (and keeping the errorbars in the legend marker)?

Comment: @DavidG it's to keep whatever is in the legend, which could be lines plotted using `errorbar` but also using `plot`. I've updated the question to clarify

Comment: If you replace the existing legend settings with this `plt.legend()`, you will get a legend with green, blue, and error bars, but is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

> A 1-1 mapping between `leg.legendHandles` and `ax.get_legend_handles_labels()` would allow for this to be accomplished, can that be done?

Yes, see the following example

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

figure, (axes1, axes2) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(8, 4))

orange = axes1.errorbar([1, 2, 3], [1, 1, 1], yerr=[.1, .1, .1], c='orange', label='orange')

axes1.legend()

axes1.plot([1, 2, 3], [2, 2, 2], c='blue', label='blue')

handles, labels = axes1.get_legend_handles_labels()

axes2.legend([handles[1]], [labels[1]])

plt.show()
```

[image]

You can also create the legend with returns of [matplotlib.pyplot.plot()](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot).

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

figure, (axes1, axes2) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(8, 4))

orange = axes1.errorbar([1, 2, 3], [1, 1, 1], yerr=[.1, .1, .1], c='orange', label='orange')

axes1.legend()

axes1.plot([1, 2, 3], [2, 2, 2], c='blue', label='blue')

axes2.legend([orange], ['orange'])

plt.show()
```

[image]

> Now, if I was given `leg`, how could I recreate the legend?
>
> I have tried
>
> `ax.legend(leg.legendHandles, [i.get_text() for i in leg.get_texts()])`

The attribute I find in [sourcecode of legend](https://matplotlib.org/stable/_modules/matplotlib/legend.html#Legend) related with handles is also `legendHandles`. This attribute is initialized in `_init_legend_box()`. The related codes are

```py
    def _init_legend_box(self, handles, labels, markerfirst=True):
        ...

        text_list = []  # the list of text instances
        handle_list = []  # the list of text instances  <-- I think this might be typo
        handles_and_labels = []

        ...

        for orig_handle, lab in zip(handles, labels):
            handler = self.get_legend_handler(legend_handler_map, orig_handle)
            if handler is None:
                _api.warn_external(
                    "Legend does not support {!r} instances.\nA proxy artist "
                    "may be used instead.\nSee: "
                    "https://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html"
                    "#creating-artists-specifically-for-adding-to-the-legend-"
                    "aka-proxy-artists".format(orig_handle))
                # We don't have a handle for this artist, so we just defer
                # to None.
                handle_list.append(None)
            else:
                textbox = TextArea(lab, textprops=label_prop,
                                   multilinebaseline=True)
                handlebox = DrawingArea(width=self.handlelength * fontsize,
                                        height=height,
                                        xdescent=0., ydescent=descent)

                text_list.append(textbox._text)
                # Create the artist for the legend which represents the
                # original artist/handle.
                handle_list.append(handler.legend_artist(self, orig_handle,
                                                         fontsize, handlebox))
                handles_and_labels.append((handlebox, textbox))

        ...

        self.texts = text_list
        self.legendHandles = handle_list
```

As we can see the `handle_list` is assigned to `self.legendHandles` at last. Values are appended to `handle_list` in the for loop as below

```py
# Create the artist for the legend which represents the
# original artist/handle.
handle_list.append(handler.legend_artist(self, orig_handle,
                                         fontsize, handlebox))

# print(f'{orig_handle} - {type(orig_handle}') gives
"""
<ErrorbarContainer object of 3 artists> - <class 'matplotlib.container.ErrorbarContainer'>
"""
```

The comment says `Create the artist for the legend which represents the original artist/handle`. But from the following example, we can see the returned artist doesn't represent the original handle. I think this might be a bug of matplotlib.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

figure, (axes1, axes2) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(8, 4))

orange = axes1.errorbar([1, 2, 3], [1, 1, 1], yerr=[.1, .1, .1], c='orange', label='orange')

axes1.legend()

axes1.plot([1, 2, 3], [2, 2, 2], c='blue', label='blue')

leg = axes1.get_legend()

handles, labels = axes1.get_legend_handles_labels()

print(f'{orange} - {type(orange)}')
print(f'{handles[1]} - {type(handles[1])}')
print(f'{leg.legendHandles} - {type(leg.legendHandles)}')

"""
<ErrorbarContainer object of 3 artists> - <class 'matplotlib.container.ErrorbarContainer'>
<ErrorbarContainer object of 3 artists> - <class 'matplotlib.container.ErrorbarContainer'>
[<matplotlib.collections.LineCollection object at 0x7f4c79919040>] - <class 'list'>
"""
```

Comment: You wrote `axes2.legend([handles[1]], [labels[1]])`, but how would you know to use `[1]` instead of `[0]`?

Comment: @ignoring_gravity Since we now the label of orange error bar, we can get this index from `labels` like `labels.index("orange")`.

Comment: what if there are multiple elements in `labels` which are `"orange"`? This seems brittle

Comment: @ignoring_gravity Practically speaking, I don't think duplicate labels have any beneficial for other people to understand your graph.

Answer (score 0):

The legend of the axes `ax` is stored in `ax.legend_`. To overwrite that, simply assign `ax.legend_ = leg`. You then need to update the axes using `ax.update_from(ax)`.

Some sample code to demonstrate, using your plots:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


#### SECTION 1 ####

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.errorbar([1, 2, 3], [1, 1, 1], yerr=[.1, .1, .1], c='orange', label='orange')
ax.plot([1, 2, 3], [3, 3, 3], c='green', label='green')
# Modifying your code a little to highlight what ax.legend() returns 
# vs what ax.get_legend() returns
leg_orig = ax.legend()
ax.plot([1, 2, 3], [2, 2, 2], c='blue', label='blue')
leg = ax.get_legend()

# ax.get_legend() is just returning ax.legend_
assert(leg==leg_orig)


#### SECTION 2 ####

# calling ax.legend() overwrites ax.legend_ with a new legend object,
# updates the axes, and returns the new legend object
leg = ax.legend()
assert(leg==ax.legend_)
assert(leg==ax.get_legend())
assert(leg!=leg_orig)


#### SECTION 3 ####

# we can manually overwite and update with the original legend
ax.legend_ = leg_orig
ax.update_from(ax)
```

Try running the code in sections to see the effect of updating the legend each time.

### Important Note

Like most mutable objects in Python, when you overwrite `ax.legend_`, the you are simply overwriting a pointer, not creating a new object. The object exists independently of `ax.legend_`, which means any changes you make to the legend object will affect all axes which share that legend object.

Answer (score 0):

The following function can duplicate a legend to a chosen axis:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def duplicate_legend(leg, axis_to):
    """Duplicate a legend to another axis"""
    labels_in = [l.get_text() for l in leg.texts]
    handles, labels = [], []
    for h, l in zip(*leg.axes.get_legend_handles_labels()):
        if l in labels_in:
            handles.append(h)
            labels.append(l)
            labels_in.remove(l)
    axis_to.legend(handles, labels)
```

Here an example:

```py
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1)

ax1.errorbar([1, 2, 3], [1, 1, 1], yerr=[.1, .1, .1], c='orange', label='orange')
ax1.plot([1, 2, 3], [3, 3, 3], c='green', label='green')
ax1.legend()
ax1.plot([1, 2, 3], [2, 2, 2], c='blue', label='blue')
leg = ax1.get_legend()

duplicate_legend(leg, ax2)
plt.show()
```

[image]

In the case of multiple labels, some hidden and some visible, only the visible ones will be added:

```py
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1)

ax1.errorbar([1, 2, 3], [1, 1, 1], yerr=[.1, .1, .1], c='orange', label='orange')
ax1.plot([1, 2, 3], [3, 3, 3], c='green', label='green')
ax1.plot([1, 2, 3], [4, 4, 4], c='green', label='green')
ax1.legend()
ax1.plot([1, 2, 3], [5, 5, 5], c='green', label='green')
ax1.plot([1, 2, 3], [2, 2, 2], c='blue', label='blue')
leg = ax1.get_legend()

duplicate_legend(leg, ax2)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: what if there's duplicate labels?

Comment: @ignoring_gravity You mean if you have duplicated labels and some of them are not visible?

Comment: I've updated the answer to handle duplicated labels: take a look, please :)